# Nextjs 'next build' runs in local but fails when Deployment to Vercel without showing any error except "Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1"

Tags: reactjs, npm, deployment, next.js, vercel

On Vercel it only shows `Error: Command 'npm run build' exited with 1` without showing any other errors, I have tried everything from refactoring to removing unused file and throwing unused dependencies to **devDependencies** but there is still no error like `module not found` or anything the build just fails
But when locally build, `npm run dev` and `npm run build` works perfectly fine

The build Log of vercel is

````
Installing dependencies...
15:18:55.150
15:18:55.151
> node-sass@4.14.1 install /vercel/path0/node_modules/node-sass
15:18:55.151
> node scripts/install.js
15:18:55.151
15:18:55.626
Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/linux-x64-83_binding.node
15:18:55.714
Download complete
15:18:55.719
Binary saved to /vercel/path0/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
15:18:55.789
Caching binary to /vercel/.npm/node-sass/4.14.1/linux-x64-83_binding.node
15:18:55.889
15:18:55.890
> core-js-pure@3.16.3 postinstall /vercel/path0/node_modules/core-js-pure
15:18:55.890
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
15:18:55.890
15:18:55.973
[96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m
15:18:55.974
15:18:55.974
[96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js:[0m
15:18:55.974
[96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
15:18:55.974
[96m>[94m https://patreon.com/zloirock [0m
15:18:55.974
[96m>[94m https://paypal.me/zloirock [0m
15:18:55.974
[96m>[94m bitcoin: bc1qlea7544qtsmj2rayg0lthvza9fau63ux0fstcz [0m
15:18:55.974
15:18:55.974
[96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m
15:18:55.975
15:18:56.213
15:18:56.213
> node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall /vercel/path0/node_modules/node-sass
15:18:56.213
> node scripts/build.js
15:18:56.213
15:18:56.472
Binary found at /vercel/path0/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
15:18:56.473
Testing binary
15:18:56.715
Binary is fine
15:18:57.319
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
15:18:57.319
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
15:18:57.320
15:18:57.326
added 991 packages from 465 contributors in 22.931s
15:18:57.795
15:18:57.795
94 packages are looking for funding
15:18:57.796
  run `npm fund` for details
15:18:57.796
15:18:57.825
Detected Next.js version: 11.1.0
15:18:57.831
Running "npm run build"
15:18:58.106
15:18:58.107
> site-redesign-react@0.1.0 build /vercel/path0
15:18:58.107
> next build
15:18:58.107
15:18:59.061
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
15:18:59.224
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
15:18:59.224
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
15:18:59.224
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
15:18:59.224
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
15:18:59.224
15:18:59.277
info  - Checking validity of types...
15:19:02.122
jsxBracketSameLine is deprecated.
15:19:13.365
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1```
````